# Max function in Oracle 12

Tags: oracle

I have two records below. I was trying to pull the latest record based from the Sold_DT, which would give me the record with 7 in Item column.

```
    Store       Sold_DT                      Item
CVS             1/22/2017 12:05:00 AM          5
CVS_S_Eleven    1/22/2017 10:41:00 AM          7
```

Here is my attempted query in Oracle:

```
select 
store, 
max(sold_dt) as max_dt, 
item
from temp
group by store, item
```

Would someone please point me to the correct direction so that I can return only the latest Sold_DT? which is only this:

```
  Store     Sold_DT                                  Item
    CVS_S_Eleven    1/22/2017 10:41:00 AM            7
```

Comment: Is Sold_DT really a date column?

Comment: Surely the latest date would be the Item 5 row?

Comment: yes. it is as date column

Comment: Are the values in the `sold_dt` column **distinct** (no two rows can have the same value)? If not - if two rows can be tied for "most recent" - then which row must be returned? Or ALL of them (ALL of the most recent rows, the rows with the most recent date-time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the MIN/MAX with KEEP. As mathguy points out, if you have two stores tied for most recent, it will get tricky and you are best to add a tiebreaker if you want a single consistent record, or use another technique if you want all ties.

```
select 
   max(store) keep (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sold_dt desc) max_store, 
   max(sold_dt) as max_dt, 
   max(item) keep (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sold_dt desc) max_item
from temp
```

Comment: @ Gary, Thanks for your unique feedback. This works perfectly! Joe

Answer (score 1):

You can take max of sold date from subquery like below and join with main table on that date value

```
select t1.*  from 
    from temp t1 join (select
    max(sold_dt) as max_dt, item
    from temp)  t2 on t1.Max_dt=t2sold_dt
```

Comment: @ Rams, Thanks very much for your input. Joe

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure if you only wanted one row if there are two with the same date and time. I assumed that you only want one. Of course, in this case there is only one row with max date anyway.

```
SQL> 
SQL> drop table temp;

Table dropped.

SQL> 
SQL> create table temp
  2  (
  3  Store varchar2(12),
  4  Sold_DT date,
  5  Item number
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> insert into temp values ('CVS',to_date('01/22/2017 12:05:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),5);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into temp values ('CVS_S_Eleven',to_date('01/22/2017 10:41:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),7);

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> 
SQL> select
  2  store,
  3  Sold_DT,
  4  item
  5  from temp
  6  where
  7  Sold_DT = (select max(Sold_DT) from temp) and
  8  rownum < 2;

STORE        SOLD_DT         ITEM                                               
------------ --------- ----------                                               
CVS_S_Eleven 22-JAN-17          7                                               

SQL> 
SQL> spool off
```